# Export SVG for ObjectBoundingBox

Tags: svg, mask, adobe-illustrator

I have very little experience with SVG and I'm trying to save a path from illustrator so that it can be used as a responsive clipping mask whose size is relative to its parent, using `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"`.

However, Illustrator doesn't seem to allow me to have relative path values between `0` and `1` and only exports absolute values.

How could I get code like this...

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <clippath id="clipping-mask">
        <path d="M49.401,64H36.3V30.648h11.201c3.9,0,7.15,0.25,10.501,2.4c4.95,3.15,7.1,8.45,7.1,14.151
    C65.102,56.75,59.352,64,49.401,64z M48.501,38.148h-3.7V56.5h3.65c5.7,0,8.15-3.65,8.15-9.051
    C56.602,42.148,54.252,38.148,48.501,38.148z"/>
    </clippath>
</svg>
```

... to be relative to its parent?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Taking a cue from Paul LeBeau's answer and from the answer at https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/42666 I figured out that you can actually set the art board in Illustrator to 1x1 and when saving to SVG increase the decimal places in the SVG Options on save. This will result in an SVG with the decimals already adjusted.

Comment: GREAT tip @stevenwoodson - exporting from Illustrator with a 1x1 size image and upping the decimal points in advanced SVG output settings! Saved a headache of manually changing decimal points and adding 0's!

Comment: Thank you! I've been scratching my head trying to understand clipPathUnits all afternoon. 

Explicit steps might be useful for dummys (like me) - Create Illustrator artboard set to 1 x 1px. Draw shape and File > Save As >  SVG. I tried File > Export in AI CC and it put all the units into decimals. Save as worked like a charm!

Comment: This other SO answer helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31210466/convert-svg-path-data-to-0-1-range-to-use-as-clippath-with-objectboundingbox#answer-54090749 
But I had to manually tweak the transform="scale(0.0040, 0.0042)" ratio a bit.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do that with Illustrator directly.  And I don't know of any tool to do the conversion.  However it is possible to do it manually with a little help from AI.

I would start by designing your clipping path on a page that is 100x100, and treat those coordinates as percentages.  Then after exporting.  Go throught the path definition adjusting all the coordinates by two decimal places.

Using your path as an example:

```
M .49401,.64
H .363
V .30648
h .11201
c .039, 0, .0715, .0025, .10501, .024
c .0495, .0315, .071, .0845, .071, .14151
C .65102, .5675, .59352, .64, .49401, .64
z
M .48501, .38148
h -.037
V .565
h .0365
c .057, 0, .0815 -.0365, .0815 -.09051
C .56602, .42148, .54252, .38148, .48501, .38148
z
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" height="200"
 viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <path d="M49.401,64H36.3V30.648h11.201c3.9,0,7.15,0.25,10.501,2.4c4.95,3.15,7.1,8.45,7.1,14.151
    C65.102,56.75,59.352,64,49.401,64z M48.501,38.148h-3.7V56.5h3.65c5.7,0,8.15-3.65,8.15-9.051
    C56.602,42.148,54.252,38.148,48.501,38.148z"/>

</svg>


<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" height="200"
 viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <clipPath id="clipping-mask" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <path d="M .49401,.64
                 H .363
                 V .30648
                 h .11201
                 c .039, 0, .0715, .0025, .10501, .024
                 c .0495, .0315, .071, .0845, .071, .14151
                 C .65102, .5675, .59352, .64, .49401, .64
                 z
                 M .48501, .38148
                 h -.037
                 V .565
                 h .0365
                 c .057, 0, .0815 -.0365, .0815 -.09051
                 C .56602, .42148, .54252, .38148, .48501, .38148
                 z"/>
    </clipPath>
     
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" clip-path="url(#clipping-mask)"/>

</svg>
```

It's a bit tedious, I know, but if you have a lot of them to do you could probably write a script for it pretty easily.